# F# Find qualified last tuple of the 3 tuples

Tags: f#

```
let dataA3 = [| ("A", 1.0M, -2.0M); 
                ("A", 2.0M, -1.8M);
                ("A", 3.0M, -1.5M);
                ("B", 2.0M, -1.5M);
                ("B", 3.0M, -1.8M);
                ("C", 1.0M, 2.0M); 
                ("C", 2.0M, 1.8M);
                ("C", 3.0M, 1.5M) |]
```

I have an array of tuples, I will find the qualified tuples.  The conditions are:

1. The first string element have to be same for 3 times, in the above example, ("A", _, _) and ("C", _, _) are qualified, but ("B", _, _) is not, as only 2 tuples contains "B"; if the number of the same first element appears more than 3 times, they are also not qualified.
2. The second decimal element has to be in ascending order and more than 0.0M;
3. The third decimal element has to be in ascending order but can be less than 0.0M;
   For example: ("A", 1.0M, -2.0M);  ("A", 2.0M, -1.8M); ("A", 3.0M, -1.5M) are qualified for the this condition; but ("C", 1.0M, 2.0M); ("C", 2.0M, 1.8M); ("C", 3.0M, 1.5M) are not qualified for this condition, as 2.0M -> 1.8M -> 1.5M is in descending order, not in ascending order.

Finally, I want to get the last tuples of the 3 tuples which qualified for the conditions.  In the above example, I want the final tuple is ("A", 3.0M, -1.5M)

```
let final = [| ("A", 3.0M, -1.5M) |]
```

If there are more tuples qualified for the condition, I need only the last of the 3 tuples for each different first string element.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another Answer

```
open System.Collections.Generic
let selectData sq =
  let dic  = new Dictionary<string, string * decimal * decimal>()
  let dicc = new Dictionary<string, int>() //counter
  for (key, v1, v2) as v in sq do
    if dicc.ContainsKey key then
      let (_, oldV1, oldV2) = dic.[key]
      if v1 > 0.0M && oldV1 <= v1 && oldV2 <= v2 then
        dicc.[key] <- dicc.[key] + 1
        dic.[key] <- v //replace new value
    elif v1 > 0.0M then
      dic.Add(key, v)
      dicc.Add(key, 1)
  for x in dicc do
    if x.Value < 3 then dic.Remove(x.Key) |> ignore
  dic.Values |> Seq.toArray

let final = selectData dataA3
```

Comment: Hello, BLUEPIXY:
Thank you very much, your last version is better and easy to understand.
Thank you very very much for your great code!
Have a nice time!
John

Comment: no problem. 
Although this may be rewritten as the characteristics of advantages and disadvantages.
 It is crucial to be able to express their thoughts think,  at first. Enjoy make code.

Answer (score 4):

For practice I removed most of the custom `fun` definitions from BLUEPIXY's code.  Also Seq.reduce is a good way to get the last value in a sequence.  It's good to understand this code and not to write it in production.

```
let tpl3_1 (x,_,_) = x
let tpl3_2 (_,x,_) = x
let tpl3_3 (_,_,x) = x

let isAscendingBy f =
    Seq.map f
    >> Seq.pairwise
    >> Seq.forall ((<||) (<=))

let filter1 =
    Seq.groupBy tpl3_1 
    >> Seq.filter (snd >> Seq.length >> (=) 3)
    >> Seq.map snd 

let filter2 =
    Seq.filter (Seq.forall (tpl3_2 >> (<) 0.0m))
    >> Seq.filter (isAscendingBy tpl3_2)

let filter3 =
    Seq.filter (isAscendingBy tpl3_3)

let choiceLast =
    Seq.reduce (fun _ x -> x)

let final =
    filter1 
    >> filter2 
    >> filter3 
    >> Seq.map choiceLast

dataA3 |> final |> printfn "%A"
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
Your code works.  But I don't quite understand '>>', tell me something about what is '>>' in your code.
Thanks and have a nice weekend!
John

Comment: @John '>>' is The functional composition. Signature is (('a -> 'b) -> ('b -> 'c) -> 'a -> 'c). mean g(f(x)) = (f >> g)(x)

Comment: it's helpful. i'll remember that "get last element by reduce" . thanks.

Comment: @gradbot: Nice technique--using `reduce` to get the last element. I changed my code to use it since it's much better than converting to a list and reversing to get the head.

Answer (score 3):

```
let isAscendingBy f sq =
  sq
  |> Seq.map f
  |> Seq.pairwise
  |> Seq.forall (fun (x1,x2) -> x1 <= x2)

let filter1 x =
  x 
  |> Seq.groupBy (fun (a,_,_) -> a) 
  |> Seq.filter (fun (_, g) -> Seq.length g = 3) // than more ? >=
  |> Seq.map snd 

let filter2 x =
  x
  |> Seq.filter (fun x -> Seq.forall (fun (_,b,_) -> b >= 0.0m) x)
  |> Seq.filter (isAscendingBy (fun (_,b,_) -> b))

let filter3 x =
  x
  |> Seq.filter (isAscendingBy (fun (_,_,c) -> c))

let choiceLast x =
  (x |> Seq.toArray |> Array.rev).[0]

let final = dataA3 |> filter1 |> filter2 |>filter3 |> Seq.toArray |> Array.map choiceLast
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
Your code works and it looks very nice and functional!

Comment: My answer is redundant but it has goodness as ad-hoc first code. After reviewing the operation step by step, do not change the behavior, I think is better optimized if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

```
dataA3
|> Seq.groupBy (fun (a,_,_) -> a)
|> Seq.filter (fun (_, d) -> 
  (d |> Seq.sumBy (fun (_,b,_) -> b)) > 0M
    && (d |> Seq.pairwise |> Seq.forall (fun ((_,x0,x1), (_,y0,y1)) -> x0 < y0 && x1 < y1)))
|> Seq.map (fun (_, d) -> d |> Seq.reduce (fun _ x -> x))
|> Seq.toArray
```

Outputs

```
[|("A", 3.0M, -1.5M)|]
```

Comment: Hello,

Thank you very much for your quick reply.
However, from my testing, the result is nothing, no qualified tuple returned.
I tried this:
let finalGroup = dataA3
               |> Seq.groupBy (fun (a,_,_) -> a)
And got all the tuples, but those tuples with "B" in are not qualified for my condition.

Comment: Did you try the full code, or just the snippet in your comment? I tested it and it works.

Comment: @ildjarn: Thanks. I always forget about that site. Very handy.

Comment: It's used religiously in `c++`, otherwise I would have never come across it. Neat that it supports F#. :-]

Comment: Hello,

Sorry, I tried your code with wrong data, so it did NOT work, but with the correct data, it worked.
Thank you very much!

Comment: (sum seq) != all one > 0 and no check group element count